# What is the right way to transform/convert from one HTML structure into another structure?

Tags: javascript, php, json, dom

**Goal**: I have a particular use case where I will get an input of HTML blocks in a particular structure from one source, and I've to transform this into another HTML structure.

**Why**: Assume the `input` structure is from 3rd party and the `output` structure is support the current platform.

**Example**
*Input*:

```
<span class="para" data-junk-id="3434">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    <b class="bold" data-junk-id="2">consectetur</b> adipiscing elit. In dui tortor, sodales nec auctor sit amet, pulvinar consequat orci. Phasellus tincidunt fermentum felis. 
    <b class="bold"  data-junk-id="43534">Sed 
        <i class="italic" data-junk-id="343434">venenatis</i> quam
    </b> id ultrices pretium. Praesent nunc magna, porttitor eget nunc non, sollicitudin egestas sapien. 
</span>
```

and the *output*

```
<p class="paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    <strong>consectetur</strong> adipiscing elit. In dui tortor, sodales nec auctor sit amet, pulvinar consequat orci. Phasellus tincidunt fermentum felis. 
    <strong>Sed 
        <em>venenatis</em> quam
    </strong> id ultrices pretium. Praesent nunc magna, porttitor eget nunc non, sollicitudin egestas sapien. 
</p>
```

Note: This will be huge HTML, above is just a sample

**Options**:
Following are the options I've

1. Convert the incoming HTML to an intermediate JSON format and create an output support structure from the JSON (In order to have a specific structure)
   ex:

```
[ // each paragraph
    {
        "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "
    },
    {
        "text": "consectetur",
        "format": "bold"
    }
]
```

2. Just walk the entire node and convert the HTML structure using `TreeWalker` with `className` & `tag` name matches
3. Create a mustache-like template and paste the structure from the input `HTML` using simple `.

**Question**:
Which will be the best and efficient way to do this?

- There is some problem I foresee in each of my above options, ex: if I each JSON, I need to handle nested tags in JSON, sometimes I feel is an overkill. But having an intermediate format seems to be good consider the cons.
- TreeWalker will help but it seems to be a hectic process, but, plus side is I have the complete control to change the flow
- Mustache, is my least preferred option, as I'm not sure I can create a template for all the sub tags which I want to convert or may be mix with the previous option.

This can be done in PHP or in JavaScript (or python), just confused about which way I can do it properly and future adaptations to these changes can be done seamlessly.

Comment: Looks like the structure is exactly the same, you're just changing the types of element (span to P, b to strong, etc.) plus some logic for carrying over or ignoring attributes. Presumably you just parse the HTML to a DOM, generate a new DOM based on element mapping rules, then serialise it. You can probably do it with recursion over nodes and their children and mapping to new node types.

Comment: Thank you @RobG. I guess instead of complicating things simple iteration will do. Just one clarification... Why do we need to serialize it?

Comment: I figured you want to go from HTML to HTML. If you don't need HTML at the end, then don't serialise. :-)